# Realizar soma dos valores de cada item igual, armazenados em um objeto e armazenar em outro array

Tags: javascript, firebase, react

Estou fazendo uma aplicaçao usando firebase e reactjs, que retorna um objeto com o fluxo de saida(outflow). Como estou usando chartjs para apresentar um grafico, preciso gerar um array onde cada posição teria a soma total referente a cada mês. Minha dificuldade esta sendo em percorrer este objeto por cada mês, calculando o total dos valores e armazenando a soma total de cada mês em outro array para apresentar no grafico.

```
const outflow = {
  '-LNpeDWzApnfSjHEJdh': {
    date: '2018-01-10',
    month: 'jan',
    name: 'Valter',
    value: 200,
  },
  '-LNpeDWzApnfSjFHlPJq': {
    date: '2018-02-02',
    month: 'fev',
    name: 'Antônio ',
    value: 250,
  },
  '-LOOg_bniqNre4xMDKN6': {
    date: '2018-01-20',
    month: 'jan',
    name: 'Bento',
    value: 200,
  },
  '-LOOg_bniheke4xMDK44': {
    date: '2018-02-22',
    month: 'fev',
    name: 'Jhon Due',
    value: 250,
  },
};

const months = [
  'Jan',
  'Feb',
  'Mar',
  'Apr',
  'May',
  'Jun',
  'Jul',
  'Aug',
  'Sep',
  'Oct',
  'Nov',
  'Dez',
];

// O resultado que preciso, seria parecido com o array abaixo. 
// Onde armazenaria na primeira posição a soma total dos valores
// referente a Janeiro, segundo Fevereiro e assim por diante.

let sumValuesMonth = [400, 500];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transforme `months` em um objeto com 12 propriedades, uma para cada mês, percorra o array `outflow` adicionando o valor do item na propriedade de `months` correspondente

```js
const outflow = {
  '-LNpeDWzApnfSjHEJdh': {
    date: '2018-01-10',
    month: 'jan',
    name: 'Valter',
    value: 200,
  },
  '-LNpeDWzApnfSjFHlPJq': {
    date: '2018-02-02',
    month: 'feb',
    name: 'Antônio ',
    value: 250,
  },
  '-LOOg_bniqNre4xMDKN6': {
    date: '2018-01-20',
    month: 'jan',
    name: 'Bento',
    value: 200,
  },
  '-LOOg_bniheke4xMDK44': {
    date: '2018-02-22',
    month: 'feb',
    name: 'Jhon Due',
    value: 250,
  },
};

const months = {
  jan: 0,
  feb: 0,
  mar: 0,
  apr: 0,
  may: 0,
  jun: 0,
  jul: 0,
  aug: 0,
  sep: 0,
  oct: 0,
  nov: 0,
  dez: 0,
};

for (key in outflow) {
  months[outflow[key].month] += parseInt(outflow[key].value);
}

document.write(JSON.stringify(months));
```

Observação: na sua pergunta o `outflow` possui o mês `fev` e o array `months` possui o mês `feb`, acredito que foi erro de digitação, se não foi terá que fazer alguma normalização

Comment: Interessante esta abordagem, achei que seria tipo combinar map(), filter() e reduce(). Obrigado, vou aplicar no sistema e tentar chegar no resultado final.

Comment: É outra possibilidade, mas assim acho que fica mais simples e fácil